# How to open GTK apps at center of screen?

Tags: gtk, webkit

1. How to code this using Quickly?
2. Will frameless GTK apps work the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `quickly design` when you are in the application's directory. This should open up glade which gives you a GUI to design your application.

When you click on the top-level window, you will see the Window Properties. In this you will find an option for "Window position", assign "center" to this field.

[image: window properties]

This will open the main window of your application in center.

Comment: Could you please try answering this question of mine?http://askubuntu.com/questions/434075/how-to-change-opacity-dynamically-in-python-and-quickly