# How to change window opacity dynamically in Python and Quickly?

Tags: application-development, python, gtk, quickly, glade

The app is written in HTML and is running using webkit and Quickly.
The opacity can be changed using Glade.

I want to add a slider functionality in HTML which will change the title of the HTML document according to the opacity.

**How to code the main `app/AppWindow.py` so that it will change the opacity dynamically according to the HTML document title?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [set_opacity](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.10/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-opacity)() method of GtkWindow object.

It will expect a float, so you should do a type conversion before.

```
try:
    self.set_opacity(float(title))
except ValueError:
    pass  # Do something with the invalid value here.
```

Comment: in my case gtk.WIndow.set_opacity() is not working. what may be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Glade doesn't add any magic function or properties to the widgets, it just uses what GTK provides.

Looking at the docs, I can find that GtkWidget has a [set_opacity()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.10/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-opacity) method. This only works since 3.8 and is the preferred way to do it. If your code also has to support GTK 3.6 and lower, use [GtkWindow.set_opacity()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.10/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-opacity)

Comment: I have found a command `self.set_opacity()` which works statically. When I dynamically code `self.set_opacity(title)` python says `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/archisman/up-clock/up_clock/UpClockWindow.py", line 86, in title_changed
    self.set_opacity("title")
TypeError: Must be number, not str
`

Comment: Why are you using "title" as a parameter for set_opacity?. It expects a number between 0 and 1, where 0 is invisible and 1 totally opaque.

Comment: @JavierRivera So that I could change the document title using a slider in HTML like [this](https://copy.com/n2JQdICihCfV). And Python would set opacity same as the title. But since it isn't supporting string variables I had to do all this. https://github.com/gabrielbarbosanascimento/Up-Clock/commit/b7ef23a3bdd32504213d8ae02671ab12813c5b4b#diff-583677f4f9ee00d4cfbe31c044660e68R75

Comment: OMG!!!!... you know, you can convert between types ;). Just do self.set_opacity(float(title)). But please note that if title has a value than can't be converted to a float the program will break.

Comment: That piece of code is a stab to the programmmer's heart :-). Just convert it to a float like Javier said and catch the `ValueError` exception.